# Pgadmin 4 Not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed postgres 10 and pgadmin4 in my Ubuntu 18.04 version. everything went fine. I cannot open the pgadmin gui. what might be the reason. it simply wont open. Does it require Qt? how do i check if I got Qt on my ubuntu? PS:  (Also Teamviewer App is also not starting up). Looks like it uses PyQt for the GUI of the application.(atleast that what i heard) 
PgAdmin 3 is working fine.
These are the steps I have done.

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository

   ```
   deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
   ```
2. Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

   ```
   wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. install posgtresql

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
   ```
4. install pgadmin 4

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
   ```

EDIT: Launching from the command line, there is a first output:

```
`QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.`
```

then as @DennyMueller mentioned, a "Fatal Error" pop-up window saying:

```
`An error occurred initialising the tray icon`
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to start the application? Can you please try again from a terminal to check for possible error messages. Please [edit] your question to describe the result. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here. pgadmin4 doenst start @ 18.04
"An error orccured initializing the tray icon" shows up after a while.

Comment: @DennyMueller We're reopening the question, so you can [edit] it and provide more information that the OP did not provide.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Just in case you get `An error occurred initialising the tray icon` then install the topicons gnome extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/